# How to map this json?

Tags: javascript, json

I never saw this structure in API. 
API' json return:

```
    {
        0: {
        lat: "-30.02091858475300000",
        lng: "-51.10401711129000000"
        },
        1: {
        lat: "-30.02080958475300000",
        lng: "-51.10340911129000000"
        },
        2: {
        lat: "-30.02079458475300000",
        lng: "-51.10332611129000000"
        },
        3: {
        lat: "-30.02075358475300000",
        lng: "-51.10310011129000000"
        },
        4: {
        lat: "-30.02071758475300000",
        lng: "-51.10289911129000000"
        },   
        idlinha: "5527",
        nome: "Santa Monica Bus",
        codigo: "4948-1"
    }
```

I tried to map on site jsonutils.com, generate this crazy code:

I used java.
The key in example may to be 0 to N, in this case is apenas 0 ... 4.

```
    public class 0
    {
        public String lat;
        public String lng;
    }

    public class 1
    {
        public String lat;
        public String lng;
    }

    public class 2
    {
        public String lat;
        public String lng;
    }

    public class 3
    {
            public String lat;
            public String lng;
    }

    public class 4
    {
        public String lat;
        public String lng;
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public 0 0;
        public 1 1;
        public 2 2;
        public 3 3;
        public 4 4;
        public String idlinha;
        public String nome;
        public String codigo;
    }
```

I had searched with the "json key value" or like it.
I need to map for javascript or angular.
Anybody would help? Or tips?

Comment: How is this question related to javascript?

Comment: The code generated in Java is correct. You should explain better what's your question. You don't understand why it's mapped the way it is? Or you need something different?

Comment: @Kobe , I need do it in Javascript or typescript.

Comment: @JosepOriolSoler: 
The weirder API return:
http://www.poatransporte.com.br/php/facades/process.php?a=il&p=5527

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nearest solution in Typescript is

```
class LatLong {
 lat: string;
 lng: string;
}

class RootObject {
 [n: number]: LatLong;
 idlinha: string;
 nome: string;
 codigo: string;
}
```

And use it with object bracket notation like that

```
obj['1'].lat
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a huge weirdness

```js
const coord = {
  0: {
    lat: "-30.02091858475300000",
    lng: "-51.10401711129000000"
  },
  1: {
    lat: "-30.02080958475300000",
    lng: "-51.10340911129000000"
  },
  2: {
    lat: "-30.02079458475300000",
    lng: "-51.10332611129000000"
  },
  3: {
    lat: "-30.02075358475300000",
    lng: "-51.10310011129000000"
  },
  4: {
    lat: "-30.02071758475300000",
    lng: "-51.10289911129000000"
  },
  idlinha: "5527",
  nome: "Santa Monica Bus",
  codigo: "4948-1"
}
Object.keys(coord).forEach(key => {
  if (isNaN(key)) console.log(key,coord[key])
  else console.log(coord[key].lat, coord[key].lng)
})
```

Comment: Still quite weird if you ask me :-). Would be wiser to go for an array of coordinates (`coords: {lat: string; lng: string}[]`). Your code is perfectly fine, but the implementation could break anytime if this response gets "weirder".

Comment: @JasonK, the weirder API return:
http://www.poatransporte.com.br/php/facades/process.php?a=il&p=5527

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks very much!
I can't evaluate your response, because this profile is new.